# Why modulo 2 can be express as cos function for optimization?

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, optimization, modular-arithmetic, approximation

I have been reading the paper [Monotonic optimization based decoding for linear codes](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-011-9816-9). In this paper the author show that modulo 2 operation can be rewritten as cos function.

Particularly, an $\left( {n,k} \right)$ with the corresponding generator matrix $G$ of size $n \times k$ is considered

$G = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{g_1}}\\
{{g_2}}\\
{...}\\
{{g_n}}
\end{array}} \right]$ each row is ${g_i} \in {\left\{ {0,1} \right\}^k}$

Let $u, x$ be the column vectors of the input bit sequence/message and the corresponding
encoder output codeword. This will give the relation $x = Gu\left( {\bmod \,\,2} \right)$. The author then show this without any proof or intuition explain

$Gu\left( {\bmod \,\,2} \right) = \frac{{{1_n} - \cos \left( {\pi Gu} \right)}}{2}$ where
$\cos \left( {\pi Gu} \right): = {\left( {\cos \left( {\pi {g_1}u} \right),\cos \left( {\pi {g_2}u} \right),\cos \left( {\pi {g_3}u} \right),...,\cos \left( {\pi {g_n}u} \right)} \right)^T}$

How can modulo 2 be express as cos function (for optimization latter in the continuous space) ?

Please help me understand this

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1-\cos0}2 = 0\\
\frac{1-\cos\pi}2 = 1\\
\frac{1-\cos2\pi}2 = 0\\
\frac{1-\cos3\pi}2 = 1\\
\vdots$$